# Query not reading the quoted string values stored in the table

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, quotes

I have stored some quoted values in a separate table and based on the value in this table. I am trying to filter the rows in another table
by using the values in this table in a subquery. But it is not reading the values for the subquery and returns a blank table in output.

The value is in column `override` and resolves to  `'HCC11','HCC12'`.

When I just copy the value from the column and paste it in place of the subquery it is fetching the data correctly. I am not able to understand the issue here. I have tried using the `trim()` function here but still its not working

Note-:  I have attached the pic for your reference:

[image]

```
select * 
from table1 
where column1 in (select override  from table 2 )
```

Comment: What exactly is the content of `column1`? Is it a single value? Does it include single quotes as well, .e.g `HCC11` or `'HCC11'`?

Comment: plse see the attached snapshot. the values is 'HCC11,'HCC12'. There can be multiple single quoted values separated by comma . I am using an IN() operator to filter the records based on these multiple values

Comment: I am talking about `table1.column1` (not the override column) - what does **that** contain?

Comment: hint: `listagg `

Answer (score 1):

Storing comma separated values in a single column is a really poor database to begin with enclosing them in quotes makes things even wors. The proper solution to your problem is a better design.

However, if you are forced to work with that bad design, you can convert them to a proper list of values using

```
select *
from table1
where column1 in (select trim(both '''' from w.word)
                  from table2 t2
                    cross join unnest(string_to_array(t2.override, ',')) as w(word)
```

This assumes that `table1.column1` only contains a single value without any quotes and that the override values never contain a comma in the real value (e.g. the above would break on a value like `'A,B', 'C'`)

Comment: column1 of my table 1 is a column based on which i have to subset it.  there are 100s of such different comma separated values  values in different rows of  override column of table 2  and if the record in table 1 contains any of these values then i just need that records. Is there a better way to store the these values that i am using from the override column ?

Comment: Btw! thanks for the sol. it worked . But if there is any other better  idea to get the task done i will work upon that

Answer (score 0):

According to your image, the value of `table1.column1` has to be `'HCC11','HCC12'` (one string) to get the match from subquery.
If the `table1` has 2 rows with values `HCC11` and `HCC12` then you might use the `exists` keyword in your subquery.
Something like

```
select * 
 from table1 t1 
where exists 
  (select 1 
   from table2 t2 
   where instr( t2.override, concat("'",t1.column1,"'") ) >=1 
  );
```

Comment: With this solution `HC11` will match with `'HC12','HC119`'

Comment: @Popeye, good point! Updated the answer. Probalby there are multiple better ways how to set the conditions of subquery.

Comment: This is invalid SQL. String constants need to be enclosed in single quotes  `"'"` is a reference to a column

Answer (score 0):

You have the override column value as `'HCC11','HCC12'` which can not match with single value `'HCC11'`. You should better use the `LIKE` operator as follows:

```
select *  from table1 t1 
where exists 
  (select 1 from table2 t2 
   where t2.override like concat('%''', t1.column1, '''%'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this like -

1.

```
select * from table1
where column1 in 
(select regexp_replace(unnest(string_to_array(override, ',')),'''', '', 'g') from table2)
```

Or

2.

```
select * from table1 
where '''' || column1 || '''' in
(select unnest(string_to_array(override, ',')) from table2)
```

Although, I would just recommend not storing your data like this, since you want to query using it.